# mvn:deploy can not invoke tomcat manager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am using mvn2, when I am trying to deploy my project using `mvn:deploy` command I am having error **can not invoke Tomcat manager** connection refused: connect below is my pom configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost/manager</url>
        <path>/scgtwitter</path>
        <server>QA</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What could be the possible solutions?

Comment: Tomcat on port 8080 perhaps so it should be `<url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>`?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that either tomcat isn't up and running (so start it), or maybe your config is wrong.
Although I have not used that particular plugin, I have used a similar one, I imagine the principal is essentially the same. This what I have:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <server>localTomcat</server>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And in the ~/.m2/settings.xml, I have supplied the username/password for the tomcat manager app:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>localTomcat</id>
    <username>tomcat</username>
    <password>tomcat</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Run with with

```
mvn tomcat:deploy
```

or

```
mvn tomcat:redeploy
```